# generate scaffold under devise user in rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, scaffolding

I use devise, and I want generate a new object scaffold under devise user sth like:

```
 resources :users, :path => "/", :only => [:show] do
   resources :collections, :controller => 'users/collections'
 end
```

With above routes, I get this url:

```
http://localhost:3000/kevin_doe/collections
```

The problem is that if I issue this command:

```
rails g scaffold users/collection title:string description:text
```

This generate a namespace sth like:

```
namespace :users do resources :collections end
```

The route that I get is:

```
http://localhost:3000/users/collections
```

**I want generate a scaffold under devise user resource.**

**How can I fix this problem?**

Thank you!

Comment: You don't do anything special to do that. You generate the scaffold and then modify routes and controller actions to reflect a nested resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix for this question are the next steps:

1º generate the scaffold with:

```
rails g scaffold collection title:string description:text
```

2º Modify your routes.rb file with the nested resource:

```
resources :users, :path => "/", :only => [:show] do
   resources :collections, :controller => 'users/collections'
 end
```

3º you must create a `"users" folder` in your controllers directory and move the `collections_controller.rb` to

```
app/controllers/users/
```

4º in `collections_controller.rb` you must modify:

```
class Users::CollectionsController < ApplicationController
.
.
.
end
```

5º In your views you must move the folder `collections` to `app/views/users/collections`

Done! :D.